# The fastest way to remove a string in a variable

Tags: bash, shell

Let's say I have a variable `foo`, that is:

```
foo=`echo ab cd ef gh`
```

If you `echo foo`, you get:

```
$ echo $foo
ab cd ef gh
```

Now, I want to remove `ef` from `$foo`. What is the fastest way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume your variable contain at least one occurrence of `ef`, POSIXly:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${foo%ef*}${foo##*ef}" 
ab cd  gh
```

In `bash`, `ksh` variants (exclude `posh`), `zsh` and `yash`, you can use:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${foo/ef}"
```

to remove the first occurrence of `ef`, or `"${foo//ef}"` to remove all occurrences.

Comment: how to remove the space created by removing "ef" ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the shell's *pattern substitution* to remove patterns:

```
$ foo="ab cd ef gh"
$ echo "${foo//ef}"
ab cd  gh
```

#### Notes

1. Many consider the use of backticks to be archaic.  The usual modern form for command substitution is `$(...)`.
2. Using backticks and echo to create `foo` is superfluous.  You may simply assign the string to the variable as shown above.
3. Just so that you are aware of what is happening, when you use echo without using putting its argument in quotes, the shell performs *word splitting*, break the string into three parts, which was feed to `echo` as three separated arguments. `echo` concatenate its argument by a space.

Answer (score 0):

Here is two ways of doing ...

```
uc@SVE1411EGXB:~/shop_app/depot2$ foo=`echo ab cd ef gh`
uc@SVE1411EGXB:~/shop_app/depot2$ echo ${foo/ef} 
ab cd gh
```

Or with  stream editor AKA `sed` .. Search for `"ef"` and replace with nothing.

```
uc@SVE1411EGXB:~/shop_app/depot2$ echo $foo | sed 's/ef//g'
    ab cd  gh
```